# c++: cin integer only

Tags: c++, input, try-catch, cin

I'm trying to validate input using try-catch blocks and have come up against a little problem.

If for the first loop, the user was to enter numbers, followed by letters (123abc), the program jumps straight to the second loop and doesn't give an error, however if reversed (abc123) the error message works fine.

Also if when inputting an int they input a double value (45.1), then the program takes 45 as the int (x), and 0.1 for the double (y). I need it to either throw the error, or will be happy if it just rounds the number to the nearest integer value

The code:

```
int x;
double y, z;

while (1)
{
    try 
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an int (x): ";
        if (std::cin >> x && x > 0) { break; }
        else if (!std::cin) { throw x; }
        else { throw x; }
    }
    catch (int)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Not a valid integer.\n\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

while (1)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a double (y): ";
        if (std::cin >> y && y > 0) { break; }  
        else if (!std::cin) { throw y; }
        else { throw y; }
    }
    catch (double)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Not a valid double.\n\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

z = x + y;
std::cout << "\n\n" << x << " + " << y << " = " << z;
```

Comment: 123abc is directly converted to 123 when put inside an `int` from a stream (at least i retested it with stringstream)

Comment: yes you're right thanks, just checked that. Also added the cin.clear() and cin.ignore() lines into the initial if statement in both loops, and now the int is rounded if it is entered as a double, thanks very much @Mayerz

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a function that takes a line of input, extracts an int from int, and checks whether there's any other garbage left. I used [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) manipulator to get rid of trailing whitespaces which should not be an error, IMO.

```
bool parse_int(int& i)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    return (iss >> i && (iss >> std::ws).peek() == EOF);
}
```

And then use it as:

```
int i;
if ( parse_int(i) ) /* ok */
```

Alternatively, if you don't care for redundant data, you can just ignore after you get an int it using [`istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Also, throwing arithmetic types is weird. Some subclass of [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) exception class would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
 std::stringstream ss;
 int x;

 ss << "123abc";
 ss >> x;
 std::cout << x << std::endl; // 123 

 // And   

 ss << "abc123";
 ss >> x;
 std::cout << x << std::endl; // 0 

 return 0;
}
```

The stream process each character one by one, and stop for an invalid caractere according to the asked type.